# google map direction in android without webview/intent

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I am working on an android application in which I pass the source address and the destination address. I need to get the turn by turn navigational directions. I need to display the direction in a dialog box (and NOT in a webview, nor do I want to open a separate browser).

Please tell me if there is any way to get the direction list in a string array. If yes, then how to accomplish it? I would then populate my dialog box with the list of directions.

Riya

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: Find a Web service that offers this feature, then use it. I do not know if there is any such service, and if it exists, it is almost certainly a commercial service.